# Page only refreshing once from dropdown list selection

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ajax to refresh a page using a parameter sent from a dropdown list to my controller. For some reason, the page only refreshes once and the dropdown list is rendered useless until I manually refresh the page from the browser. In the controller, I'm using a switch statement depending on the parameter sent to make calls to a Couchbase server to retrieve database items. How can I get the page to refresh more than once using the dropdown list?

//View

```
@model List<Merchandise>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Variant Summary";
}

<body class="variant" id="load">

    <div class="pageMain">
        <div class="variant-page">
            <div class="container-variant">
                <header>
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-dark ">
                        <div class="container">
                            <h3>
                                <img src="~/images/3bars_menu_header.png" /> Variant Summary
                            </h3>
                            <div id="merchTicker">
                                <div class="inner">
                                    <ul position="absolute"></ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            @Html.DropDownList("Countries", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Countries))), new { @id = "countrylist" })

                            @section Scripts
                                {
                                <script type="text/javascript">

                                        $("#countrylist").change(function () {
                                        var select = $("#countrylist").val();
                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: "get",
                                            url: '@Url.Action("Merchandise", "Home")' + "/" + select,
                                            data: {'selCountry' : select},
                                            success: function (data) {
                                                $('.variant').html(data);
                                            }
                                        });
                                        });

                                </script>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </header>

            </div>
            <table class="merchTable">
                <tr>
                    <th width="75px">SEQ</th>
                    <th width="125px">Item ID</th>
                    <th width="700px">Description</th>
                    <th width="90px">Sold</th>
                    <th width="90px">Sold Today</th>
                    <th width="90px">AFS</th>
                    <th width="65px">P Mins</th>
                    <th width="65px">A Mins</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.PlanSeqId</td>
                        <td>@item.ItemId</td>
                        <td>@item.ItemDescription</td>
                        <td align="right">@item.OrderQuantity</td>
                        <td align="right">@item.OrderSldTdy</td>
                        <td align="right">@item.AvaiForSaleQty</td>
                        <td align="right">@item.PlannedMinutesQty</td>
                        <td align="right">@item.ActualMinutesQty</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
```

//Controller method

```
public IActionResult Merchandise(Countries selCountry)
        {          
            switch (selCountry)
            {
                case Countries.USA:
                    var bucket = _bucketProvider.GetBucket("MerchUSA");
                    var n1ql = @"SELECT g.*, META(g).id
                                FROM `MerchUSA` g
                                WHERE g.CompanyId = 0
                                LIMIT 20;";
                    var query = QueryRequest.Create(n1ql);
                    var results = bucket.Query<Merchandise>(query);
                    UpdateMerchSold(results.Rows);
                    return View(results.Rows);
                case Countries.EUR:
                    var bucket2 = _bucketProvider.GetBucket("MerchEUR");
                    var n1ql2 = @"SELECT g.*, META(g).id
                                FROM `MerchEUR` g
                                WHERE g.CompanyId = 1
                                LIMIT 20;";
                    var query2 = QueryRequest.Create(n1ql2);
                    var results2 = bucket2.Query<Merchandise>(query2);
                    UpdateMerchSold(results2.Rows);
                    return View(results2.Rows);
                case Countries.JPN:
                    var bucket3 = _bucketProvider.GetBucket("MerchJPN");
                    var n1ql3 = @"SELECT g.*, META(g).id
                                FROM `MerchJPN` g
                                WHERE g.CompanyId = 2;
                                LIMIT 20;";
                    var query3 = QueryRequest.Create(n1ql3);
                    var results3 = bucket3.Query<Merchandise>(query3);
                    UpdateMerchSold(results3.Rows);
                    return View(results3.Rows);
            }
            return View();
        }
```

I'm still learning ajax, so any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you check data in success callback of ajax, is the "data" is updated and expected html?

Comment: When I select a country from the dropdown, it sends the parameter to my controller, which makes the call to couchbase and displays the correct data for that country. The only problem is I can't select another country until I refresh the page from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rebind the click event.  You are replacing all the html including the select list.  This cause it to lose its event listener.

I'd also suggest moving your script section out from the middle of your html and drop it to the bottom.  Easier to read.

Comment: Thanks! And yes I agree on moving it to the bottom, will do.

Comment: I have another question, sorry. When the page reloads, the dropdown refreshes back to USA, even though the data is showing the different selected country. How can I keep the selected item in the dropdown when the page reloads?

Comment: Best answer is to make your table a partial view and in your controller use that new partial.  Then in the success method of your ajax call put the data object there instead of replacing the entire page.  This will fix your original issue of needing rebinding and your drop down will retain the selected value

Comment: Also, if you wanted to get super fancy smancy you could use Datatables.net.  look into the ajax datasourse. Http://www.datatables.net.